Example that $x \in$ Var(Id($A$)) but $\forall$ countable $B \subseteq A, x \notin$ Var(Id($B$))
Could you give example for the following 2 cases:
Suppose $X$ is a space with Zariski topology over uncountable field $k$

$x$ is in Zariski closure of $A$, but $\forall$ countable $B \subseteq A, x$ is not in Zariski closure of $B$
$\forall$ countbale $B$ which $x$ is in Zariski closure of $B$, $x$ is in Zariski closure of $B \cap A$, but $x$ is in Zariski closure of $X-A$.

context:
I am constructing examples for the following 2 cases:

Suppose $X$ is not first countable: 
(1) $x \in \bar{A} \not\Rightarrow$ $x$ is a limit of a sequence of points in $A$.
(2) every sequence limit to $x$ is eventually in $A \not\Rightarrow$ $x \in \text{Int}(A)$

I had one with co-countable topology on $\mathbb{R}$:

Let $A = \mathbb{R}-\{0\}$, $0 \in \bar{A}$ but there is no sequence in $A$ limit to $0$. If any sequence limit to $0$, then after finite terms, the sequence will be all $0$. Thus, every sequence limit to $0$ is eventually in $\{0\}$. However, $0$ is not an interior point of $\{0\}$

I know that Zariski topology over uncountable field is not first countable. So I translate the proposition into the following form:

$x$ is in Zariski closure of $A$, but $\forall$ countable $B \subseteq A, x$ is not in Zariski closure of $B$
$\forall$ countbale $B$ which $x$ is in Zariski closure of $B$, $x$ is in Zariski closure of $B \cap A$, but $x$ is in Zariski closure of $X-A$.

Did I translate these statement correctly? If yes, how to construct such example? Thanks in advance.
